# How to set the working directory to an older commit?

Tags: git, working-directory

To track down at which point I broke a feature in my software, I need to review older versions of my repository. I just want to set the working directory to an older commit, play with the code, afterwards discard the changes, and then try another commit.

I do not want to change anything about commits, neither remove nor create ones. I tried using `git reset` but after that newer commit weren't shown anymore. So I downloaded the repository again, because I didn't know how to revert that.

Comment: I came to this after googling "[swap working directory to an earlier commit but leave head unchanged](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=swap+working+directory+to+an+earlier+commit+but+leave+head+unchanged)". I ended up using `git checkout <earlier-commit-hash> -- <file-path>` for each of the files I wanted to revert to the earlier commit

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A simple `git checkout old-sha1` can be a start, but the real command  for that kind of task is:

**[`git bisect`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect)**.

> Find by binary search the change that introduced a bug

If you have a script able to test if your working tree "works" or not, you can execute that script on previous commits through `git bisect`, locating the first commit which breaks your test.

Note that this command isn't yet supported directly by GitHub for Windows: you will have to open a shell.

---

A `git checkout` would leave you in a detached HEAD, which doesn't matter since you won't make any modification.
To get back to were you were, checkout a branch:

```
git checkout master
```

See "[Why did git detach my head?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)".

Comment: Thanks, I thought `checkout` is only for branches before. Which kind of script could I use for `bisect`? My application is written in native C++. By the way I am impressed by Git to include such a command.

Comment: @danijar no, you can checkout any treeish. For instance, `git checkout "@{10 minutes ago}"` would give you the commit from 10 minutes ago.

Comment: @danijar for git bisect, any script you want as long as it exits with status 0 (works) or 1 (fails).

Comment: I used `checkout` and Git told me I am in "detached Head" state now. What does that mean? How can I get back to the newest commit?

Comment: @danijar I have edited the answer to address the detached head aspect.

Answer (score 12):

You can checkout the code in another branch to the index by using the following:

```
git checkout my-other-branch .
```

The dot is a path specifier indicating you want to do this for the entire repository. You could likewise specify only a specific folder. Technically, you can specify any 'tree-ish' specifier for the `my-other-branch` parameter, such as a tag, a commit hash, something like `HEAD~1`, ect... If you want these changes to be unstaged, you could then do:

```
git reset HEAD
```

Assuming you began in a clean state, you'll now have your working directory be in the same state as `my-other-branch`.

Comment: This one worked for me. Without dot specifier files in work directory was not restored.

Answer (score 4):

Using `git checkout <branch_name>` you can switch to the other available branch. If you want to reset your `HEAD` to the older commit, you can try the following command :

- git reset --hard HEAD~1 to reset the HEAD by **a single commit**
- git reset --hard HEAD~2 to reset the HEAD by **2 commits** and so on

Also if you have the commit, then you can try this command : `git reset --hard <commit>`
In this way you can set the working directory to an older commit.

To completely discard the changes you can try : `git reset --hard` which will clean your directory to the previous commit.